# Pass parameter as query string to ajax call of fancybox from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax, fancybox

I am working on asp.net web page where i am showing you-tube videos using fancy-box.

So far it is working fine, I also need to make an ajax call to asp.net file `UpdateVideoViews.aspx?VideoID=xyzxvtmiw`  so that i can update the hits/views for this video in the database (when someone clicks the thumbnail).

So far it is working fine i am able to show videos in fancy box and make an ajax call simultaneously also but problems is that i am not able to pass `youtubeVideoID` query-string to part of ajax script so that it fetch the youtubeVideoID for the correct video click.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "UpdateVideoViews.aspx?youtubeVideoID=7oR4411Pza0",
     });
```

Below is part of my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Code to Reinitialize Fancybox script when using update panel START
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) { InitMyFancyBox(); }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitMyFancyBox();
    });

    function InitMyFancyBox() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".youtube").click(function () {
                // first, get the value from the alt attribute
                var newTitle = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); // Get alt from image
                $.fancybox({
                    'padding': 0,
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    //'title': this.title, // we will replace this line
                    'title': newTitle,  //<--- this will do the trick
                    'width': 680,
                    'height': 495,
                    'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                    'type': 'swf',
                    'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UpdateVideoViews.aspx?youtubeVideoID=7oR4411Pza0",
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    }
</script>

            <asp:Repeater ID="rptvideos" runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="single-video-wrapper">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hylnkvideo" CssClass="youtube"  NavigateUrl='<%# getVideoURL(Eval("VideoID"), Eval("VideoYoutubeID")) %>' runat="server">
                        <div class="video-image-wrapper">
                            <asp:Image ID="imgvideo" ImageUrl='<%# getVideoImagePath(Eval("VideoYoutubeID"), Eval("VideoYoutubeIcon")) %>'   AlternateText='<%# getVideoTitleDesc(Eval("VideoDate"),Eval("VideoTitle"),Eval("VideoDesc")) %>'  runat="server" CssClass="video-thumbnail" />
                        </div>
                       <div class="video-name">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblvideoName" CssClass="video-name-lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("VideoTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="video-issue">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblVideoIssue" CssClass="video-issue-lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#getIssuCode(Eval("IssueCode")) %>'></asp:Label>
                       </div>
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I would appreciate help in this regard

Comment: Have you tried using the `data` setting? (pass the `youtubeVideoID` as data) check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more